# How to rename a remote host name?

Tags: vscode-remote

I want to rename a name of remote host retaining history (i.e., workspaces opened before) under it.

Renaming `Host` in the ssh config file does not retain the history.

Is there a database which contains the information?

Does anyone know the way?